# Facebook SDK install APP with install confirmation

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I am looking for help to validate when a Facebook APP has been installed. I am currently using PHP SDK to have the clients sign in and in the same manor I would like for them to return to the site once the APP is completed and installed correctly.

Is there a method to use this link and have it return with the client id?
https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=XXX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=XXX` for any cases other addition of application to page as a tab (and even this is undocumented).

If you're using PHP-SDK you should use [`Facebook::getLoginUrl`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) to log user in, which support `redirect_uri` parameter so you can add client id as argument to this URL

**Update:**. 
As it turns question is about adding application tab to page you should be using [Add Page Tab Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) to provide user with a way of "installing" application to page without leaving your app.

You can refer to answers on [How to add tab application to a page with the "new auth dialog"](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8596217/how-to-add-tab-application-to-a-page-with-the-new-auth-dialog) for more info.

**Update 2:**
How to reach applications running as Page Tab described in *"Integration with Facebook APIs"* section of [Page Tab Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/):

> your application will also receive a string parameter called `app_data` as part of `signed_request` if an `app_data` parameter was set in the original query string in the URL your tab is loaded on. For the Shop Now link above, that could look like this: `http://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=any_string_here`. You can use that to customize the content you render if you control the generation of the link.

You not required to add `app_data`, just use `v=app_APPID` to link to your page tabs (Facebook itself using `sk` instead of `v`, both works).

Comment: I am using the `Facebook::getLoginUrl` and `Facebook::getLogoutUrl` to signin and signout. This is working. I like to now provide a link to install a APP and return back after it being installed. This is the last part I cannot find.

Comment: Perfect .. I am now testing this out!

Comment: That was the magic link I was looking for.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I have another question - hope you can answer. I use the URL as noted above. How do you get Facebook to pass the `[page][id]` to make the page tabs work?

Comment: This sounds like you have to setup a Canvas Page. I am looking to have the add page tab (as mentioned in Update 1) on my site - forward client to Facebook, install tab and return with signed request.

Comment: I just did some testing and each time I add a page tab I get `?tabs_added[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]=1#_=_` I assume that this is the page id as in the two tests I did this matches the actual ID.